# Simultaneous using of Touchscreean LCD and MCP3008 on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: pi-3, touchscreen, spi, analog-to-digital

I want to use a touchscreen LCD (3.5" TFT) and a MPC3008 ADC at the same time to monitor data fast and continuously in my project. 
And I know the data interface of each three parts (LCD, touch, and MPC3008) is SPI.

Now here are my questions:

1) Is it possible to use all 3 devices at once?

2) If yes, should I use an auxiliary SPI to handle it? How would I do that?

3) If No, what's your suggestion?

4) What changes should I make to both code and configuration?

This issue is very important for me. Please Help.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: How far have you got?  Where is your current code?

Answer (score -1):

I use spidev1.0 to make it both work together.

To activate it :

1. Edit `/boot/config.txt`
2. Check if spi is activated or add new line `dtparam=spi=on`
3. Activate SPI 1.0 adding line `dtoverlay=spi1-1cs`
4. Now wire your devices according to following mapping :

   ```
   - CLK = pin 40 (GPIO 21)
   - MOSI = pin 38 (GPIO 20)
   - MISO = pin 35 (GPIO 19)
   - CS/SHDN = pin 12 (GPIO 18)
   ```

Comment: Please see original (updated) post.